# How to fetch time using Time class in Android?

Tags: android, time

I need to get the Current time in a string format in android. I have seen a `toString` method in Time class.  Is there any way to get the current time using Time class or object in android? If not, how can I get the current time as a string in android?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I do it:

```
Date date = new Date();
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getBaseContext());
dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities:

1. Automatically use the user-preferred format:

   ```
   String dateString = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(thisContext).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
   ```
2. Use your own format:

   ```
   String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this

```
Time time = new Time();

    System.out.println("time = " + time);
    System.out.println("time.toHour() " + time.toHour());
    // etc..

    // Test with a supplied value
    Time time2 = new Time(12033312L);
    System.out.println("time2 = " + time2);
```

also

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

       //get current date time with Calendar()
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```